# centering a transparent menu

Tags: html, css, center

I am trying to make my transparent menu appear **centered**, but whatever method I dig up from the internet, nothing seems to do the trick.

I would really love if someone could look through this code, and give me a hand. :)

**The HTML-part:**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="menu">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="print">PRINT</a></li> 
        <li><a href="tv">TV</a></li> 
        <li><a href="other">OTHER</a></li> 
        <li><a href="resume">RESUME</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**The CSS part:**

```
#container 
{   
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family:arial;
    height:400px;
}

#menu 
{   

    float: left;  // **WHENEVER I CHANGE THIS FLOAT, THE MENU-BACKGROUND DISAPPEARS?!**
    position: relative;
    display:inline;
    border:2px solid #000;
    border-top:0;
    border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
}
#menu .bg 
{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity:0.5;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
#menu li 
{ 
    float:left;
}
#menu a 
{
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
    padding:8px 13px;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    z-index:2;
    float:left;
}
#menu a:hover 
{
    color:#999;
}
```

Comment: Please consider a less verbose title - something short that describes the issue is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by updating `#menu` to:

```
#menu {   
    position: absolute;
    border:2px solid #000;
    border-top:0;
    border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -152px;
    width: 305px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAnLt/1/)

Comment: This did it for me, thank you very very much! I only had to change width to a slightly higher value! =) 
Thank you @daGUY

Comment: No problem. Don't forget that the negative left margin is half the width, so if you change the width at all, you'll have to adjust the left margin to match to keep the menu in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Centering floats is difficult. Here's one method:

```
<style type="text/css">

#container
{   

font-family:arial;
height:400px;
border: red;
position: relative;

}

#menu
{   

position:relative;
left:-50%;
float:right;
}

ul
{
position:relative;
left:50%;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
overflow: hidden;
}

li{
display:block;
float:left; 
padding: 8px 13px;
}

a {text-decoration:none;}

</style>
<div id="container">
<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="print">PRINT</a></li>
    <li><a href="tv">TV</a></li>
    <li><a href="other">OTHER</a></li>
    <li><a href="resume">RESUME</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Source: http://browse-tutorials.com/snippet/center-floats-css
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yucHM/2/

Comment: This simply made my menu disappear I am afraid, but thanks for trying @coopersita

Comment: I modified it to match your code. It's slightly different, but it should be easy to customize. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yucHM/3/

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your menu is not centering, is because you do not have a defined width for either the menu or the container. If you had a defined width, then you would be able to use:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

I'm not sure yet why your float starts messing up your background colors, however I did notice you missed a semicolon at the end of one of your style properties

```
#container 
{
padding: 10px 0 0 0
...
}
```

should be

```
#container 
{
padding: 10px 0 0 0;
...
}
```

Comment: I tried, but couldn't make it work, I did find a solution among the ones below yours, but thank you very much Sam Huckaby! :) The ; as well! ^.^

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

EDITED CSS:

```
#container 
    {   
        display: inline-block;
        *display: inline;
        zoom: 1;
        padding: 10px 0 0 0
        overflow:hidden;
        font-family:arial;
        height:400px;


    }

    #menu 
    {   

        float: left;  // **WHENEVER I CHANGE THIS FLOAT, THE MENU-BACKGROUND DISAPPEARS?!**
        position: relative;
        display:inline;

    }
    #menu .bg 
    {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:#000;
        opacity:0.5;
        filter:alpha(opacity=50);
        left:0;
        top:0;
    }
    #menu ul {          <===Added this definition and moved the border here as well
       clear:left;
       float:left;
       list-style:none;
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       position:relative;
       left:50%;
       text-align:center;
        border:2px solid #000;
        border-top:0;
        border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    }
    #menu li 
    { 
        float:left;
    }
    #menu a 
    {
        text-decoration:none;
        position:relative;
        padding:8px 13px;
        color:white;
        font-weight:bold;
        z-index:2;
        float:left;
    }
    #menu a:hover 
    {
        color:#999;
    }​
```

EDITED HTML (closed a div tag)

```
<div id="container">
<div id="menu">
    <span class="bg"></span>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="print">PRINT</a></li> 
        <li><a href="tv">TV</a></li> 
        <li><a href="other">OTHER</a></li> 
        <li><a href="resume">RESUME</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>​
```

And here's the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jcurran/yucHM/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I figured out the centering thingy with daGuy's reply. But your edited HTML part was great, thank you so much! =) 
Have a good evening sir!